# Tokenizing using boost gives out the same output

Tags: c++, boost, tokenize

I want to tokenize a lot of Burmese text. So I tried using `boost` tokenizer.

The text that I was trying with is `ျခင္းခတ္ခဲ့တာလို႕` and it should get tokenized to `ျခင္း` and `င္းျခင္း` but it just outputs the input. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
    #include<string>

    int main(){
        using namespace std;
        using namespace boost;
        string s = "ျခင္းခတ္ခဲ့တာလို႕";
        tokenizer<> tok(s);
        for(tokenizer<>::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg){
                cout << *beg << "\n";
        }
    }
```

The output should break into a series of tokens like: `ျခင္း` and `ခတ္ခဲ့တာလို႕` but currently, the output is equal to input.

*I want to tokenize this into a series of tokens with word boundaries if possible.*

Comment: Are you sure about your tokens? I know nothing about burmese, but they're overlapping and don't cover the whole string. Also, don't you need a custom separator here?

Comment: Your code example may be missing a `boost::char_separator`, so it will be broken on space characters.  Is there a `' '` (U+0020) UTF-8 space character between the two tokens?

Comment: @Quentin I have updated the outputs. Sorry for the incorrect output.

Comment: @Eljay Could you suggest an example? Space was unnecessary. I have trimmed it.

Comment: There is an example in the Boost Tokenizer documentation, [char_separator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/tokenizer/doc/char_separator.htm).

Comment: You may have to treat the unicode utf-8 sequence as a full string of utf-8 encoding units, in which case [splitting strings](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100693/Splitting-strings) will be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand that language, but detecting word boundaries is, in general, **not** tokenizing.

Instead, use [Boost Locale's Boundary Analysis](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/locale/doc/html/boundary_analysys.html)

The sample:

```
using namespace boost::locale::boundary;
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::string text="To be or not to be, that is the question."
// Create mapping of text for token iterator using global locale.
ssegment_index map(word,text.begin(),text.end(),gen("en_US.UTF-8")); 
// Print all "words" -- chunks of word boundary
for(ssegment_index::iterator it=map.begin(),e=map.end();it!=e;++it)
    std::cout <<"\""<< * it << "\", ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Would print

```
"To", " ", "be", " ", "or", " ", "not", " ", "to", " ", "be", ",", " ", "that", " ", "is", " ", "the", " ", "question", ".",
```

And this sentence `"生きるか死ぬか、それが問題だ。"` would be split into following segments in ja_JP.UTF-8 (Japanese) locale:

```
"生", "きるか", "死", "ぬか", "、", "それが", "問題", "だ", "。",
```

### DEMO

A demo using the OP's text and the my_MM locale:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/261ad7c15f29e128)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/locale/boundary.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::locale::boundary;
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::string text="ျခင္းခတ္ခဲ့တာလို႕";

    ssegment_index map(word,text.begin(),text.end(),gen("my_MM.UTF-8")); 

    for (auto&& segment : boost::make_iterator_range(map.begin(), map.end()))
        std::cout << std::quoted(segment.str()) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
"ျ"
"ခ"
"င္း"
"ခ"
"တ္"
"ခဲ့"
"တာ"
"လို႕"
```

This may, or may not be what the OP expects. Note that you might have to generate/install the appropriate locale(s) on your system for it to work as expected.

Comment: Added a live demo with the OP's sample text